# Git repository very large object files

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket repository that used to contain many data (csv) files whose size exceeded 1GB. 
At some point we decided to remove those files from the repository via gt rm.
Now the repository size is reduced. However, some very large git objects exist in the .git folder. Those objects have a size more that (800MB) keeping the repository site very large.

```
19M ./.git/objects/f2
21M ./.git/objects/38
25M ./.git/objects/6e
27M ./.git/objects/12
27M ./.git/objects/a5
27M ./Visualization
30M ./TS
31M ./Databases
41M ./RT/logs
59M ./RTS
64M ./BS
64M ./BS/Old
581M    ./.git/objects/pack
876M    ./.git/objects
877M    ./.git
```

How can I remove those files?

Comment: @Sze-HungDanielTsui: This comment deserves a caveat:  It will delete the local copy of your repository and all the history.

Comment: @SvenMarnach YES. Silly me. Better to google around on how to look at hidden folders and delete the files you want.

Comment: Deleting those files would break the history and as such the point of version control. Even if you decided that the files are no longer needed now, they were part of the past history.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in Git repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100907/how-to-remove-delete-a-large-file-from-commit-history-in-git-repository)